# Is it possible to take scrollbar out the container to the document?

Tags: css

```
.cnt
  overflow: auto
```

https://codepen.io/DTX/pen/qjjyEe

I want it to look like scrollbar on the image:
[Img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HsbgF.png)

P.s. Why is there 1px line at the end of content?

Comment: 1px line: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLfuF.png

Comment: I cannot replicate the issue. Chrome V 58

Comment: White line or black outline

Comment: @Ihazkode, http://i.imgur.com/aDp62Ho.png

Comment: @Mr_Panda, white

Comment: https://image.ibb.co/kFz83Q/Capture.png

Comment: hm.. i have Chrome V58.0.3029.110  too. thx anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can cheat that by removing `overflow: auto` from `.wrap` and adding extra overlay to hide the overflowing content:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PjjBxE

Comment: thx. but 1px gap is still there :)  may be you have any ideas? http://i.imgur.com/uEAt4TW.png

Answer (score 1):

You may use a mask and let body overflows: https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/jwwpXQ

```css
.wrap {
  height: 80vh;
  margin: 10vh 10vw;
  width: 80vw;
}

.wrap:before {/* here comes the mask hidding edges with a white shadow */
  content: "";
  position: fixed;
  top: 10vh;
  bottom: 10vh;
  left: 10vw;
  width: 80vw;
  border: solid 1px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 10vw white;
  pointer-events: none;/* will not catch pointer-events and will let pointer-events occurs within .wrap */
}

.sidebar {
  text-align: center;
  background: rgba(170, 170, 170, 0.7);
  height: 80vh;
  position: fixed;
  width: 20vw;
  left: 10vw;
}

.sidebar button {
  margin: 5px;
}

main {
  background: #FFAB91;
  margin-left: 20vw;
}

header {
  background: #ccc;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

header span {
  background: #aaa;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 12px;
  margin-top: 9px;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 90px;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}

.item {
  height: 100px;
  background: #ddd;
  margin: 20px;
}

.cnt {
  padding-bottom: 10vh
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="sidebar">Sidebar</div>
  <main>
    <header><span>  </span></header>
    <div class="cnt">
      <div class="item"><a href="">click me</a> or select me </div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
      <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
  </main>
</div>
```

Comment: thx, it works. But @Jacob Desight offered a easier solution and i cant two posts as answers

Comment: @DTXqueque no problem, it is your question ;) the extra markup or the virtual pseudo do the same thing being fixed to create a mask , one uses a shadow, the other a border . same visual effects, **Did you checked if you could select your text or reach a link or a form via the mouse ?** , my proposal does  ...

Comment: yeah, you are right, i can't. But using box-shadow i can select text through shadow. I guess i should use preudo-elements here.

Comment: @DTXqueque yes and no, it is about pointer-events. pseudo can have a border and extra div can have a shadow.  pseudo only needs to update the css file, extra element needs to update both . both solution are efficient, the best is the one you understand and handle the best ;)